# How to delete "are you sure you want to leave this page" dialog box in js

Tags: javascript

I have two forms on my page.
When I submit one form appears dialog box - "are you sure you want to leave this page".
How can I remove or accept it in page code?

Comment: code please! we cant help you without any code or Fiddle.
For your information that message does not came from the web site code is a browser thing.

Comment: @AjayMakwana: Not "or." The code **must** be in the question, not just linked.

Comment: Could you provide more info about which framework or libs you are using, part of code where it is exist and so on?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the suggetion. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

somewhere in your code you have something like `window.onbeforeunload` which calls second dialog box.